# \W in regex not matching

Tags: regex, pcre

I've got this regex:

```
s/[abgn][\W].*/
```

I want to match those Examples:

- a.M.X.y.Z
- b
- g/S/d%k/k

I dont want to match:

- aM.X.y.Z
- spam

I hope you see, that if I want to match a string, the second char shouldn't be a word char.
But my regex did not work. It matches, although there is the \W.
I don't know why it is not matching.

Comment: Why have you just got `abgn` in your character class?

Comment: because the first string is only allowed to be a,b,g or n. (IEEE 802.11)

Comment: @PeterI Your regex works for every example stated except the **b** and its solution is already there.

Comment: @NaveedS You are completely right, I made a mistake. BattleBit gave me the right answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to use

```
s/[abgn]([\W].*|$)/
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you've used s/ at the beginning but here's an expression that should work for you

```
[abgn](?!\w)[\w\.]*
```

the (?!\w) is a negative lookahead expression meaning that [abgn] must not be followed by a \w

this should match
a.M.X.y.Z
b

and not
ab
aX

Comment: I did use s/ at the beginning, because this is how you use regex in perl. (I use perl ^^)

Comment: ok then add s/ and try. I've just modified the exp because (?!\w) was not being displayed. It should work if pearl supports negative lookahead

Comment: oh, i did not notice your g/s example. BattleBit's answer is correct. Also just add ^ if you want the match to start at the beginning of a line. Nice tool at gskinner.com by the way :)